# Toggling DIV while displaying name from JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a webpage with `login and register` inside a DIV. When login is clicked it takes the user to login page. On a successful login it,the user is re-directed to the previous page now inside of `login and register` it must display `welcome (username)` . The login verification is done in `JSP`. I need a way to toggle between two div when the user logs in.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="pull-left">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="pull-right">
            <li>Welcome to our Store</li>
            <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a>

            </li>
            <li>or</li>
            <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a>

            </li>
            <li>yourself!</li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="pull-right1">
            <li>Welcome</li>
            <li>
                <%=session.getAttribute( "username")%>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( <%= session.getAttribute("username") %> ) == "" {
        $("#pull-right").hide(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try  like

```
<%if(session.getAttribute("username").equals("")){%>
     <ul id="pull-right"> 
        <li>Welcome to our Store </li>
        <li><a href="login_page.html">Login</a></li>
        <li>or</li>
        <li><a href="register_page.html">Register</a></li>
        <li>yourself!</li>
      </ul>
<%}else{%>
      <ul id="pull-right1">
        <li>Welcome</li>
        <li><%=session.getAttribute("username")%></li>
      </ul>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score -1):

if(<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>) == ""{

it must be:

if("<%=session.getAttribute("username")%>") == ""{